# Error while adding Firebase as a dependency to Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create a Swift Package for use across projects and I got it up and running in a private repo, I can add it to my projects, but I am unable to get its dependencies to work. At the moment I am getting the following error:

x-xcode-log: product 'FirebaseCore' required by package 'sacore' target 'SACore' not found in package 'firebase-ios-sdk'.

FirebaseCore does exist as a package in firebase-ios-sdk and so far I tried:

- resetting the package cache
- resolving package versions
- updating packages
- commenting out FirebaseCore
- renaming FirebaseCore to Firebase

If I remove FirebaseCore I will get an error saying: No such module 'GoogleUtilities_NSData'

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SACore",
    //    platforms: [.iOS(.v16)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SACore",
            targets: ["SACore"]),
    ],
        dependencies: [
            // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
            .package(url: "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", from: "1.0.0"),
            .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk", from: "10.0.0"),
            .package(url: "https://github.com/kylebshr/ScreenCorners", from: "1.0.0"),
            .package(url: "https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero", from: "1.6.0"),
        ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "SACore",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseCore", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseFirestoreSwift", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "CryptoSwift", package: "CryptoSwift"),
                .product(name: "ScreenCorners", package: "ScreenCorners"),
                .product(name: "Hero", package: "Hero"),
            ],
            path: "Sources",
            sources: ["Classes", "Extensions", "Constants.swift", "Shared Assets.xcassets"]
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: I managed to get this to work by removing FirebaseCore from the list of dependencies and going nuclear on XCode to get it to pick up the changes. Right click on dependencies and choose 'Reset Package Caches', clean build, quit and clear derived data. Delete Package.resolved from your package base directory. Open ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/repositories/ and deleted any relevant packages (you could just delete them all as they're cached and will just be re-downloaded). Re-open the package and wait for it to re-download and re-resolve.